# Deployable Spring Boot Wars OAuth2 Denied Exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have three spring boot applications, one is a derby spring boot and the other two have OAuth2 (org.springframework.security.oauth2) one has the OAuth2 client and the other the OAuth2 server. I have converted them to deployable wars and deploy them to a tomcat, they seems to be running fine. Except for the OAuth2, it seems to be failing in the deployable wars. I'm seeing this error:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:145)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.java:44)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:648)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.headForHeaders(RestTemplate.java:336)
```

I have debug both executable and deployable and the only thing I have found is that in the executable wars the OAuth2AccessToken has a value but in the deploy wars in tomcat the OAuth2AccessToken is null.

I'm able to get the token with `curl` and I have check that the url is correct in the application.

I've also try to deploy the derby spring boot in a separate tomcat and that makes the OAuth2 to start working, not sure why.

I'm not sure why this is happening since the wars are the same. Am I missing some configuration in tomcat?

Or maybe some conflict with the classes deployed in tomcat? Or the tomcat classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I once faced similar issue. I deployed my Spring Boot application on AWS and I was getting the same error. I was deploying the .war file and running the Tomcat separately on AWS. I fixed the error by deploying the .jar file which itself includes the tomcat server. Not sure if the scenario is same.